# xbee arduino uno doesn´t connect

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, xbee, arduino-due

I have 2 arduino uno and 2 xBee S2 and I want them to comunicate between each other. I have no shield, I just conect whith jumpers to the protoboard, using the ports 0 and 1 from the arduino to the Xbees but they are not connecting, I have them whith DL and DH sincronised. Does someone have any solution or idea? I even tried connecting whith a duemilanove.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the part of your code where you initialize the Xbee on the arduino and what do you do to send/receive data. Do you use a library ? search for Arduino Xbee library and everything should be ok ^^

Answer (score 0):

If your using ARDUINO 1.5.3 no need of XBee libraries.
If you want to just communicate two XBee then you need to install X-CTU, for this no need of writing code in Arduino you can see the data transfer and receive in X-CTU only.
If you want to use the input data of XBee for calculation purpose then In XBee port 2 and 3 are used for DI and DO so connect these two port to Arduino and use the code for transmission of data.